# ordinary differential equation: $(f'(z))^2 = c\,f(z)^3 + f(z)^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I swear I have seen this type of ODE before, but I can't remember how to attack it. In general, I would like to know how to solve $$\left(f'(z)\right)^m = c\,G(z)^n$$ where $m,\;n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $G(z)$ is just a polynomial in $f(z)$.

This sounds hard, so I would be happy with, $$\left(f'(z)\right)^2 = c\,G(z)^n,$$ though this latter equation may be too difficult too. For my homework, though, I need to know, $$\left(f'(z)\right)^2 = \left( c\,f^3 + f^2 \right).$$ It was also suggested in the homework question to utilize $$g^2 = 3\,c-f.$$ If I do this without thinking I get an equation $$\left(f'(z)\right)^2 = c\,f(z)^2,$$ which seems much easier, though I am still a little rattled by the plus-minus.

In case it matters, this is a related to a method for solving the Korteweg-deVries equation, $$u_t + u\,u_x + u_{xxx} = 0.$$ I have seen some solutions (but did not understand them) where the polynomial was "factored" into 3 roots... something like that. I just don't want to know the answer, but how to get it. Please keep in mind that this is my first class in PDEs.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Yes, I was there too.... I was thinking for some reason there may be some complications due to the sign of the square root. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: "I have seen some solutions (but did not understand them) where the polynomial was "factored" into 3 roots" - and that is precisely the Weierstrass approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation is not too hard to solve.

$$\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{dy}{dz}\right)^2 &= cy^3+y^2\\
\frac{dy}{y \sqrt{cy+1}} &= dz\\
cy+1 &= u\\
2 \frac{du}{u^2-1} &= dz\\
- 2 \tanh^{-1} u + C&= z\\
u &= \tanh \frac{-z+C}{2}\\
\sqrt{cy+1} &= -\tanh \frac{z-C}{2}\\
cy+1 &= \tanh^2 \frac{z-C}{2}\\
y &= \frac{\tanh^2 \frac{z-C}{2}-1}{c}\\
y &= -\left({c\times \cosh^2 \frac{z-C}{2}}\right)^{-1}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Aaahhh, I think that the $g^2 = 3\,c-f$$ must have been a hint towards a substitution in the integration. Turns out it was just confusing the way it was suggested in the problem. Now I see it as a straight-forward problem.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 3):

There is this famous differential equation ...
$$
[\wp'(z)]^2 = 4[\wp(z)]^3 - g_2\wp(z) - g_3
$$
[Weierstrass Elliptic Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions#Differential_equation)

Comment: Ahh. Thank you - I was also wondering how I was going to solve this pde if I wasn't able to get rid of 2 BC's - would lead to a third-order polynomial in p(z) just like you mentioned.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to complete GEdgar's Weierstrass solution. Start with the differential equation

$$(f^\prime (z))^2 = c\,f(z)^3 + f(z)^2$$

and introduce a new function $g(z)$ satisfying the relation

$$f(z)=\frac4{c}g(z)-\frac1{3c}$$

(This is essentially equivalent to "depressing" a cubic equation plus a rescaling.)

We can then derive a differential equation for $g(z)$ through this substitution:

$$(g^\prime (z))^2=4g(z)^3-\frac1{12}g(z)+\frac1{216}$$

and comparing this with the Weierstrass differential equation, we find that

$$g(z)=\wp\left(z;\frac1{12},-\frac1{216}\right)$$

We then compute the discriminant

$$\Delta=\left(\frac1{12}\right)^3-27\left(-\frac1{216}\right)^2=0$$

and find that the underlying cubic is *degenerate*. Abramowitz and Stegun give [appropriate formulae](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_651.htm) for the case of $\Delta=0$, $g_2 > 0$, and $g_3 < 0$ (see formula 18.12.3); applying the formula listed there yields

$$\wp\left(z;\frac1{12},-\frac1{216}\right)=\frac1{12}+\frac14\mathrm{csch}^2\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)$$

and thus

$$f(z)=\frac4{c}\left(\frac1{12}+\frac14\mathrm{csch}^2\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)\right)-\frac1{3c}=\frac1{c}\mathrm{csch}^2\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)$$

Note that I only derived a *particular* solution; the modifications necessary for a general solution (i.e., taking the constant(s) of integration into account) is left as an exercise to the reader.